# else function runs but it shouldnt

Tags: python-3.x

```
    print("enter your age")
age = int(input())
if age < 21:
    print("no beer")
if age > 21:
    print("what beer do you like?")
beer = input()
if beer == "union":
    print("this is water")
if beer == "jelen":
    print("great")
else:
    print("aren't you drinking ? ")
```

After typing union it also runs else function. why ?

Comment: You need to give more information. The else will run exactly when it's supposed to, so your condition must be wrong. You need to say what you expect though.

Comment: check the type of beer `type(beer)` also print it

Comment: @Carcigenicate The title of the question literally says the `else` branch -
 only one in the code sample - should not run. That's the expected behaviour.

Comment: @millimoose After looking it over, yes, I determined what they were going for. That hardly excuses what essentially is a code-only question though.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an `elif`:

```
if beer == "union":
    print("this is water")
elif beer == "jelen":
    print("great")
else:
    print("aren't you drinking?")
```

Otherwise your two `if`s get interpreted separately:

```
# first condition
if beer == "union":
    print("this is water")
# end first condition

# second condition
if beer == "jelen": # beer is 'union', this branch doesn't run
    print("great")
else: # beer is not 'jelen', so this branch runs
    print("aren't you drinking ? ")
# end second condition
```